# can't login in new user via ssh 'server refused our key'

Tags: centos, ssh

There are a number of similar questions, for example [SSH: "Server refused our key" with no reason](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156038/ssh-server-refused-our-key-with-no-reason)

However, I've gone through the suggested checks and can't seem to get a new user to connect via ssh. This is my process;

`useradd username` > `passwd username` etc...

I've checked the home directory permissions for the new user after that which = `700` as suggested in other posts. (`~/.ssh/` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` are `700/600` respectively)

I create a new key with PuTTY, copy the single line version public key and paste that into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` under the rest.

I then try to connect via PuTTY (or stfp using the same key) specifying the new username and .ppk file, but just get told the server has refused our key.

**In the past I've added new keys for the root user successfully**, but adding a new user and a key is failing to work.

I tried adding a .ssh folder and authorized_keys file in the users /home/username directory as another post suggested to no avail.

The relevant parts of my sshd_config are;

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
```

I have **no** Allow or Deny lines present

/var/log/secure shows the following;

> Jul 14 11:20:44 www sshd[18632]: Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx: 14: No supported authentication methods available
>
> Jul 14 11:22:08 www sshd[18629]: Received signal 15; terminating.

I'm pretty new to Linux command line, but from all the Googling I've done, it sounds like I've done this in the right order, so I don't know what I might be missing.

**EDIT**

`ssh -vvv user@server` generates;

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to www.xxxxxx.com [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellma                 n-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.c                 om,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,ae                 s256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,ae                 s256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac                 -sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac                 -sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellma                 n-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,ae                 s256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,ae                 s256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac                 -sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac                 -sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 123/256
debug2: bits set: 498/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 0 for host www.xxxxxx.com
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 2 for host www.xxxxxx.com
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host www.xxxxxx.com filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug2: no key of type 3 for host www.xxxxxx.com
The authenticity of host 'www.xxxxxx.com (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 4a:8f:8d:4c:7a:bd:be:63:e7:04:5b:51:ae:34:fb:80.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'www.xxxxxx.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 485/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1165
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1213
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f68bf9e7f10)
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1277
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 127.0.0.1.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_0' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I'm not sure what most of this means, however there is no mention of the new users ssh key, if that's pertinent...

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not much help, I just get the following; **Jul 14 11:20:44 www sshd[18632]: Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx: 14: No supported authentication methods available
Jul 14 11:22:08 www sshd[18629]: Received signal 15; terminating.**

Comment: `No supported authentication methods available` means that either client or server does not support public key authentication. What does the client log `ssh -vvv user@server` looks like?

Comment: @Jakuje I've added the output of that command as an edit. Both the client and server do work with public keys when logging in as root.

Comment: Check once more the permissions and owners of the files: `ls -ldZ ~username/ ~username/.ssh ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys` Especially if you created them under the root account.

Comment: @Jakuje AHA! You've got it. I had tried creating `/user/.ssh` and `authorized_keys within that, previously, but I never thought to check/change the user:group. I've changed it to the new users details and it works! Feel free to put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only permissions matters, but also the user and group. You should be able to notice that from the below output:

```
ls -ldZ ~username/ ~username/.ssh ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This is common mistake, especially if you create the folders using `root` user.